# what's best way to requesting related data from 2 different microservices?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, microservices, communication

I have an e-commerce application just for learning purposes based on microservices architecture. I have an `api-gayeway` that routes the incoming requests to the microservices.
I have a `checkoutservice` that orchestrates 3 microservices which are `payment`, `email` and `shipping` microservices. There is a `cartservice` that stores products in redis as `cartId` => `productId`, `productQuantity`. and a `postgressql` db that stores the whole product information connected to `catalogservice`.

So, when a client wants to order the items, they need to checkout. So, in redis that connected to `cartservice` only holds the products' ids and quantities for the current user. I am using pubsub `rabbitmq` fanout type for the `checkout`, `payment`, `shipping` `email`. So, basically I want to send all the products information to those 3 microservices from `checkout`.

I am planning to make a get request from `checkoutservice` to `cartservice` to get the productIds and their quantities and then based on those Ids, I want to make a get request to the `catalogservice` to get the related products' names and prices.

Since, it will be sync and it will cause a cycle between microservices which eventually increases the overall response time for the clients, I don't think it is efficient.

What can be the best approach to get products' all information? Maybe `checkout` to `cartservice` and then `cartservice` to `catalog` to get all information and finally send back to the `checkoutservice` to spread the whole product information using rabbitmq to other services?

[image]

Here is the architecture to better understanding. I am asking the communication on question marks.

> If your microservice needs to raise an additional action in another microservice, if possible, do not perform that action synchronously and as part of the original microservice request and reply operation. Instead, do it asynchronously (using asynchronous messaging or integration events, queues, etc.). But, as much as possible, do not invoke the action synchronously as part of the original synchronous request and reply operation.

> And finally (and this is where most of the issues arise when building microservices), if your initial microservice needs data that's originally owned by other microservices, do not rely on making synchronous requests for that data. Instead, replicate or propagate that data (only the attributes you need) into the initial service's database by using eventual consistency (typically by using integration events, as explained in upcoming sections).

The above statemens are from Microsoft's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture

Considering that I am storing the cart items in redis connected to `cartservice` like:

```
cartId: {
 {
  productId: 10,
  productQuantity : 1
},
 {
  productId: 20,
  productQuantity : 2
 }
}
```

and whole item information in `catalogservice`'s database like:

```
cartId: {
 {
  productName: "CCC"
  productDescription: "CCCDDD"
  productId: 10,
  productPrice : 10.50
},
 {
  productName: "AAA"
  productDescription: "AAABBB"
  productId: 20,
  productPrice : 20.50
 }
}
```

Should I also replicate necessary part of the data in `checkoutservice` using eventual consistency?

Answer (score 2):

I think that cart service shouldn't be a separate microservice on its own because it doesn't have a specific function other than store temporarily the products of a given customer.

I think that the most efficient way to do it is by merging checkout and cart services. So the action to do the checkout was part of the responsibilities of cart-service. You can think of it as a service that accumulates the products of a given customer and in some moment can check out or discard them.

This way you can query the product information in parallel when the user does the checkout or even get the product info asynchronously whenever a new product is added to the cart. and then send the whole information to the other services using the message queue

Comment: as you said it does have a specific function and it is the main reason why microservices are built based on this?. i can't say what you're saying does not make sense but general convention i've seen is that cart services are seperated. so, im gonna keep it the way it is. any other suggestion? thanks.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you as a cart is just an order with SHOPPING_CART status.